# Select or add entity to a form

Tags: symfony

You can use the [entity type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) to let a user select from among the current set of entities, or an [embedded form](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#embedded-forms) to let him add a new entity.

My question is, how can you do both (i.e. offer a select field as well as an 'Add New' field)?

My builders are

```
$builder->add('customer', 'entity', array(
    'class'    => 'TechrescueAdminBundle:Customer',
    'property' => 'label',
));
```

and

```
$builder->add('customer', new CustomerType());
```

but of course, one will overwrite the other if I have both.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089861/symfony2-collection-of-entities-how-to-add-remove-assotiation-with-existing-en